# Function defined with name from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list of strings and I want to generate functions like this:

```
f_names = ["func1", "func2", "func3"] #and possibly many more   
def generate_functions():
    for funcname in f_names:
        def <funcname value>(*args):
            another_function(<funcname value>, *args)
```

Obviously I can't do that with code sample above.

What is the best way to accomplish my goal? Is it:

- Generating temporary .py file with all `def` instructions and importing everything from it?
- Using `exec()` and generating def instructions in string?
- Using classes and `__call__()`?
- Using Python built-in tools? (If so what tools?)

Comment: It does not anwser my question. I want to have globally accesible functions, not a dictionary.

Comment: That does answer your question. Using global dynamically created variables is a terrible idea. Make a dictionary, and stick the functions in the dictionary. You'll want to use `lambda` though, not `def`.